# Javascript Max Min Avg

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the Max, Min, Avg to this code with an expected output of `[10,-2,3.5]`

```js
function MaxMinAvg (arr){

    var max = arr[0]
    var min = arr[0]
    var sum = arr[0]

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){

    if (arr[i] > max){
    max = arr[i]
    }
    if (arr[i] < min){
    min = arr[i];
    }
    sum = sum + arr[i];
    var avg = arr[i] / arr.length;
    var arr2 = [max, min, avg];
    }
    return arr2;
    }
```

```
[10,-2,3.5]
```

Comment: What is the question? You showed the desired output, but not any input. And you did not say anything about the problem with your code

Comment: `var avg = arr[i] / arr.length;` <-- that ain't the average

Comment: Homework question:

Given an array with multiple values, write a function that returns a new array that only contains the maximum, minimum, and average values of the original array. (e.g. [1,5,10,-2] will return [10,-2,3.5])

How do I structure my code to get the AVG 3.5 on this one?

Comment: You have weighted average in avg, but average is sum of particular avg(s) or sum/arr.length after for loop (1st can have big error, 2nd can overflow in sum).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, but you need to move `avg` calculation and final array creation ***outside*** the for loop. Also, the average would be the sum divided by total units.

```js
const maxMinAvg = arr => {

    let max = arr[0];
    let min = arr[0];
    let sum = arr[0];
    
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){

      if (arr[i] > max){
        max = arr[i]
      }

      if (arr[i] < min){
        min = arr[i];
      }

      sum = sum + arr[i];
    }

    return [max, min, sum / arr.length];;
};

console.log(maxMinAvg([1, 5, 10, -2]));
```

A *slightly* more succinct version using array::reduce:

```js
const maxMinAvg = arr => {
    const [max, min, sum] = arr.reduce(([max, min, sum], current) => {
      if (max < current) max = current;
      if (min > current) min = current;
      sum += current;

      return [max, min, sum];
    }, [arr[0], arr[0], arr[0]]);

    return [max, min, sum / arr.length];;
};

console.log(maxMinAvg([1, 5, 10, -2]));
```